# Matlab - wait for the end of a callback function

Tags: matlab, semaphore

I have a program using two timers. The first one allows me to communicate with a microcontroller every second and to update charts, and I use the second one to stop the program after 50 seconds if the user did not press stop button before. The problem is that I don’t know how to wait the end of the execution of the callback function of the first timer before ending the program. Sometimes, it stops in the middle of the first callback. I would like to avoid that, but I don’t know how. I tried to use “waitfor”, but it doesn’t work. 
Here is a simple example with the same problem.

```
t = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period', 1,'TimerFcn',@testWait); 
fwait = figure('Visible','off'); 
start(t); 
disp('start'); 
pause(5); 
delete(fwait); 
i=0; 
while true
    waitfor(fwait);
    disp(int2str(i)); 
    pause(0.05);
    i = i + 1;
end

function testWait(src,event)
    disp('before');
    waitfor(evalin('base','fwait')); 
    disp('after');
    assignin('base','fwait',figure('Visible','off')); 
    pause(1); 
    delete(evalin('base','fwait')); 
end
```

Can someone help me please ! :)

Comment: I only see one timer in your example. Where's the second one?

Comment: @gnovice This is just a general example where the waitfor command does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *uiwait* and *uiresume*. Here's a code snippet for how to use it:

```
f = figure;
h = uicontrol('Position',[20 20 200 40],'String','Continue',...
              'Callback','uiresume(gcbf)');
disp('This will print immediately');
uiwait(gcf); 
disp('This will print after you click Continue');
close(f);
```